# how to query sqlite json1

Tags: json, sqlite

I 'm novice of using SQLite 3 with JSON1.
I'd like to query json file.

This is my json file

```
{
    "customer": {
        "_id": "6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44",

    },
    "invoices": [{
            "_id": "12db73e71874f0db72bf1a44de02ee69",
            "invoice": 215,
            "payments": [{
                    "invoice_id": "12db73e71874f0db72bf1a44de02ee69",
                    }
            ],
            "items": [{
                    "invoice_id": "12db73e71874f0db72bf1a44de02ee69",
                    "given_id": "TBC0003B",
                    }
            ]
        }, {
            "_id": "5feade559d6ff105f6c8fce7d6e4278f",
            "invoice": 149,
            "payments": [{
                    "invoice_id": "5feade559d6ff105f6c8fce7d6e4278f",
                    }
            ],
            "items": [{
                    "invoice_id": "5feade559d6ff105f6c8fce7d6e4278f",
                    "given_id": "TBC0002B",
                    }
            ]
        }, {
            "_id": "28cfd52546e7527b8bb1d6bc0b92ae44",
            "invoice": 136,
            "payments": [{
                    "invoice_id": "28cfd52546e7527b8bb1d6bc0b92ae44",
                    }
            ],
            "items": [{
                    "invoice_id": "28cfd52546e7527b8bb1d6bc0b92ae44",
                    "given_id": "TBC0002B",
                    }
            ]
        }, {
            "_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
            "invoice": 117,
            "payments": [{
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    }
            ],
            "items": [{
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "BAP0009A",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "FSS0024B",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "DJX0001E",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "LPHEHSM",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "MSN0037",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "given_id": "MSO0008.6.5",
                    }, {
                    "invoice_id": "11377999af6610dd9956e4608acd6953",
                    "id": "TBC0001A",
                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

when I query as the following:

```
sqlite> SELECT json_extract(data, '$.customer._id') , A.value , B.value FROM dataset,json_tree(data) AS A,json_tree(data) AS B WHERE (A.key='invoice' and A.value != 0) AND (B.key='given_id' and B.value NOT LIKE '6%');
```

I got the result as

**6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0003B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,BAP0009A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,FSS0024B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,DJX0001E
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,LPHEHSM
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,MSN0037
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,MSO0008.6.5
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0001A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,TBC0003B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,BAP0009A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,FSS0024B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,DJX0001E
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,LPHEHSM
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,MSN0037
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,MSO0008.6.5
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,TBC0001A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,TBC0003B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,BAP0009A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,FSS0024B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,DJX0001E
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,LPHEHSM
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,MSN0037
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,MSO0008.6.5
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,TBC0001A
.
.
.**

Actually I'd like to get the result as:

**6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0003B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,149,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,136,TBC0002B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,BAP0009A
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,FSS0024B
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,DJX0001E
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,LPHEHSM
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,MSN0037
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,MSO0008.6.5
6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,TBC0001A**

Could you please teach me how to do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain the logic of you attempt and your expectation. Why do you query like that? Why do you expect like that?

Comment: thanks for reply. I'd like to extract **invoices.items.given_id** based on **customer._id** and **invoices.invoice**. So first result of query should be **6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44, 215 , TBC0003B** instead of looping of all **invoices.items.given_id**

Comment: Why do you expect different from what you get? You seem to expect fewer lines than you get; why? Which part of your query do you expect to cause the expected output but is contradicted by the output you get?

Comment: Or is there no conflict between query and result and you just want somebody to write a query which has the desired result?

Comment: Please read JSON file that I provided. Based on this JSON file, correct result will be the ones with fewer lines. As under **invoices.invoice (215)**, there is only **invoices.items.given_id(TBC0003B)**. But wrong loop in query and got more lines that I mentioned.Thanks

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: For the **invoices.invoice (215)** `6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0003B 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0002B 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0002B 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,BAP0009A 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,FSS0024B 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,DJX0001E 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,LPHEHSM 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,MSN0037 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,MSO0008.6.5 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,215,TBC0001A` , there is only one **given_id** that is **TBC0003B**. But my wrong query give these result.

Comment: For the **invoices.invoice (215)**, the expected result should be **6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44, 215 , TBC0003B**. But I don't know how to query.

Comment: But for the **117** (invoices.invoice), result should be `6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,BAP0009A 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,FSS0024B 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,DJX0001E 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,LPHEHSM 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,MSN0037 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,MSO0008.6.5 6a7e5fbd48a14d39aedb23ab104c1d44,117,TBC0001A` As under invoices.invoice (117), there are 7 invoices.items.given_id **(BAP0009A,FSS0024B , DJX0001E,LPHEHSM ,MSN0037 , MSO0008.6.5 ,TBC0001A)** Could you notice it ?

Comment: If the question is "Why?" then I expect an answering explanation to contain a "because". Yours only contains "is ... but should be ...". Also, please add explanations to the question itself, by [edit]ing it. Don't hide helpful information down here in the comments.

Comment: Is JSON1 support built in to the .NET drivers?